# Error with line-breaking in cvlistdoubleitem in moderncv

Tags: errors, line-breaking, moderncv

I'm experiencing a strange asymmetry in how `moderncv`'s `\cvlistdoubleitem` command handles line-breaking.  This code compiles perfectly.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{References}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Prof. Charles Xavier\\Trinity College, Cambridge}{Prof. John Frink}

\end{document}
```

However, when I switch the line-breaking to the second part of the `\cvlistdoubleitem`, it doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{References}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Prof. Charles Xavier}{Prof. John Frink\\Trinity College, Cambridge}

\end{document}
```

In the latter case, I get the following error message.

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
>   \csuse #1->
>              \ifcsname #1\endcsname \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \fi 
>   l.9 ...of. John Frink\Trinity College, Cambridge}

Why does the problem occur in one case but not the other?

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it using `\newline` instead of `\\`.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{References}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Prof. Charles Xavier}{Prof. John Frink \newline Trinity College, Cambridge}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, thanks!  However, I'd still like to know why.